# How to get FB Ad Account Id via API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

With new facebook ads API. How do I find all the ad account ID's associated with a user?

I see all the documentation about how to get details about an Account (given id). But I can not find how to get a User's ad account id (via api)
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/adaccount/v2.3

Please advise.

Answer (score 19):

Hit the /me/adaccounts path to retrieve accounts your access token (and app) can read.

See the Edges section of the user Graph API documentation for the adaccounts edge: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user

Comment: do you know if the user-id is the one that you get packed inside the accessToken you get when you request permissions... i'm trying that, getting 803. https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/165682874473626&access_token=EA....

Answer (score 5):

This has helped me and I hope will help someone else too one day.

These are the steps to achieve campaign list after oAuth.

**Step 1 (Front-end):**

Do authentication frontend side with following URL:

```
https://www.facebook.com/v3.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=<client_id>&redirect_uri=<URL>&scope=email%2Cads_management%2Cads_read&response_type=code&state=<state>
```

**Step 2 (Front-end + Backend):**

`Step 1` will give `code` object, pass it to backend

**Step 3 (Backend):**

Fetch `access-token` of user using following API

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/oauth/access_token?client_id=<client_id>&redirect_uri=<redirect_URL>&client_secret=<client_secret>&code=<code-from-front-end>
```

**Step 4 (Backend):**

Fetch Ads account details:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/me/adaccounts?access_token=<access_token_from_step_3>
```

**Step 5 (Backend):**

Fetch Campaigns list:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/act_<account_id_from_step_4>/campaigns?access_token=<access_token>&fields=id,name,objective,configured_status,effective_status,account_id,bid_amount,bid_strategy,start_time,end_time,targeting,daily_budget,campaign_id,special_ad_categories
```

Here you will get Campaign list of authorized user.

Note:

- If your facebook app is under development mode then make sure you added authenticating user in your `Admin/Developer/Tester` list
- Make sure authenticating account is having Campaigns